# retrieve data from manytomany field in the sequence of it was saved django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I Have a Invoice system where employee or staff can create invoice and can add multiple product and quantity for the specific customer . as i am using mysql i cant take json data or an array data .so i was taking the quantity and price( after discount and other modificaion) as a string and then when showing or printing the invoice i used regex to find the quantity and price .i added product ids in a manytomay field from where i am getting the product name and selling price. while showing the data on printing page in when i use zip the products are showing as the id of the product so i want to retrive the data the way it is being saved . or could you tell me any way to do it more easier way?
Here is my **models.py**

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    total = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amounts = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="00")
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Invoice.objects.count():
            self.id = 20210001
        else:
            self.id = Invoice.objects.last().id + 1
        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my views.py of printing page function

```
def final_billing(request, id=None):
    pk = id
    obj = Invoice.objects.get(id=pk)
    products = obj.products.all()
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=obj.customers.id)
    amn = obj.amounts
    qt = obj.quantity
    list_of_comma = re.findall("[\d+.+\d]+", amn)
    amnts = [float(n) for n in list_of_comma]
    list_of_quantity = re.findall('[0-9]+', qt)
    qty = [int(n) for n in list_of_quantity if n.isdigit()]
    products = list(products)
    both = zip(products,amnts,qty)
    return render(request, 'finalbill.html',{'bills': obj, "due": customer, "both": both})
```

I want it to be retrieved the product objects in the sequence of it was saved

Answer (score 1):

The query can only be sorted with a specific field, Django cannot guess otherwise, so in your case the best case is to sort your products by the date they were created, for example :

```
obj.products.all().order_by("created")
```

This suppose that you have a "created" field that is added each time a product is save in your database.

Another way of doing it is to specify the **through option**, from the documentation :

> you can use the through option to specify the Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to use.
> The most common use for this option is when you want to associate extra data with a many-to-many relationship.

The through table contains an the primary key of the relation, you can use that to retrieve the sequence in which your objects were added.

for example :

```
    from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="membership_invites",
    )
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

[Through Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Comment: Its gonna be the same as it is now . But i want to retrieve the way it was being set in manytomany field.

Comment: Ok so in that case I have updated my answer, you need to redesign your model but fortunately Django provide a nice option for you.

Comment: thanks for you helps.but the thing is my scenario is something more different . my way of showing wasnot good . now i have updated my question .if you please check and help me with it i would be glad.